# Microsoft Teams encryption verification

Tags: encryption, hash, man-in-the-middle, sha256

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-security-guide) suggests that MS Teams calls are encrypted and can be verified by reading out the 20-digit security codes found on the endpoint computers.

*To protect against a man-in-the-middle attack between the caller and callee, Teams derives a 20-digit security code from the SHA-256 thumbprints of the caller’s and callee’s endpoint call certificates. The caller and callee can validate the 20-digit security codes by reading them to each other to see if they match. If the codes don’t match, then the connection between the caller and callee has been intercepted by a man-in-the-middle attack. ...*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-security-guide

... but I cannot find documentation on how to find these codes in MS Teams. Additionally, encryption appears to be present for multiple endpoint calls with the same problem.

How do I verify encryption, short of a packet capture?

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot find documentation on how to find these codes in MS Teams

It is described here: [Use end-to-end encryption for one-to-one Microsoft Teams calls](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/use-end-to-end-encryption-for-one-to-one-microsoft-teams-calls/ba-p/2867066).

> How do I verify encryption

In theory, you can check if such encryption is applied by disassembling the binaries. In reality, it can be nearly impossible, because the code may be pretty complex.

MS Teams is not open source. That's why you have only to trust Microsoft that the code is really implemented as Microsoft says. If you see that this means some risks to you, it is up to you to accept these risks and to use MS Teams, or not to accept and not to use MS Teams.

> short of a packet capture

Even if you would capture the whole traffic, you would not be able read it, because it is encrypted by TLS. That's why you would not be able to detect, if MS Teams implements end-to-end encryption within TLS.

Does e2e encryption use TLS? I don't know. But I suppose it does. Because otherwise implementing e2e encryption would mean essentially more effort. For instance, one would have to reimplement solution for perfect forward secrecy, reimplement protection against replay attacks (replay of intercepted TLS traffic). This functionality is provided by TLS out of the box.